# Java regex to detect, and transform on, both case and type changes

Tags: java, regex

Java 11 here, I'm trying to use regexes to build a method that accepts a `String`, transforms it, and returns the transformed results.

Specifically, the string **must** only contain 1+ alpha-numeric characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9]+`). Anytime two consecutive characters/elements either change case or switch from alpha -> numeric (and vice versa), I want to insert a hyphen (`"-"`) between them.

Hence:

```
INPUT             RESULT
====================================
flimFlam          flim-Flam
fliMflam          fliM-flam
fliM8fLam         fli-M-8-f-Lam
flim$Flam         Illegal! $ not allowed!
```

My best attempt so far:

```
public String hyphenate(String input) {

    // validate
    String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal!");
    }

    // TODO: how to efficiently iterate down the 'input' string and insert hyphen
    // whenever case changes or 2 consecutive elements switch from alpha -> numeric
    // or numeric -> alpha ?

}
```

**Any ideas as to how to accomplish this *hyphenation* efficiently?**

Comment: The way `flimFlam` becomes `flim-Flam`,  `fliMflam` should become `fli-Mflam`.

Comment: Whats with the DV? Its on topic, is not a dupe, shows research/effort and is an SSCCE. Change my mind!

Comment: You are right. I do not see a reason why it should be DVed. In fact, it is worth UV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regex lookarounds we can try:

```java
String input = "fliM8fLam";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])", "-");
System.out.println(output);  // fli-M-8-f-L-am
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can check for a non-alphanumeric character using `[^\\p{Alnum}]`. Learn more about patterns from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
2. You can get the matching groups using `[a-z]+(?=[A-Z\d])|[A-Z]+[a-z]+|\d+|[A-Z]`. Learn more about this pattern from [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/TjgEL6/1). You can concatenate the matching groups using a regular loop or the Stream API as shown in the following demo.

**Demo**:

```
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] arr = {
                "flimFlam",
                "fliMflam",
                "fliM8fLam",
                "flim$Flam"
        };
        for (String s : arr) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Trying to hyphenate " + s);
                System.out.println(hyphenate(s));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static String hyphenate(String input) {
        if (Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Alnum}]").matcher(input).find()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal!");
        }

        String regex = "[a-z]+(?=[A-Z\\d])|[A-Z]+[a-z]+|\\d+|[A-Z]";
        return Pattern.compile(regex)
                .matcher(input)
                .results()
                .map(MatchResult::group)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Trying to hyphenate flimFlam
flim-Flam
Trying to hyphenate fliMflam
fli-Mflam
Trying to hyphenate fliM8fLam
fli-M-8-f-Lam
Trying to hyphenate flim$Flam
Illegal!
```